# Quartus II VHDL code problem - what do I do?

Tags: compiler-errors, vhdl

I'm trying to compile my VHDL code in Quartus II but it doesn't compile because apparently, there is one (1) error. Problem is, the program isn't showing me where the error is or what the error is. I've been at this for days. Can someone help?

BTW I know that the code is for a VHDL package, the main code is OK, it's just that Quartus II throws an unknown error at me and I don't know what to do. I've tried everything - adding stuff, removing stuff, but it still throws me the "[file name] was NOT successful (1 error)".

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
package package1 is
    component NOT1
        generic(DELAY: time:=5ns);
        port(in1,in2: in std_logic; out1: out std_logic);
    end component;

    component AND2
        generic(DELAY: time:=5ns);
        port(in1,in2: in std_logic;out1: out std_logic);
    end component;

    component OR2
        generic(DELAY: time:=5ns);
        port(in1,in2: in std_logic;out1: out std_logic);
    end component;

    component XOR2
        generic(DELAY: time:=5ns);
        port(in1,in2: in std_logic;out1: out std_logic);
    end component;

    component ADD3
        generic(DELAY:time:=5ns);
        port(in1,in2,cin: in std_logic;sum,cout:out std_logic);
    end component;

    component INVERT3
        generic(delay:time:=5ns);
        port(in1,in2,in3:in std_logic; out1:out std_logic);
    end component;

    component OPERATION5
        generic(delay:time:=5ns);
        port(in1,in2,in3,in4,in5:in std_logic;out1:out std_logic);
    end component;
end package package1;

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
package body package1 is

    entity AND2 is
        generic(delay:time);
        port(in1,in2:in std_logic;out1:out std_logic);
    end AND2;
    architecture model_conc of AND2 is
        begin
            out1 <= in1 and in2 after delay;
    end model_conc;

    entity NOT1 is
        generic(delay:time);
        port(in1:in std_logic;out1:out std_logic);
    end NOT1;
    architecture model_conc1 of NOT1 is
        begin
            out1 <= not in1 after delay;
    end model_conc1;

    entity OR2 is
        generic(delay:time);
        port(in1,in2:in std_logic;out1:out std_logic);
    end OR2;
    architecture model_conc2 of OR2 is
        begin
            out1 <= in1 or in2 after delay;
    end model_conc2;

    entity XOR2 is
        generic(delay:time);
        port(in1,in2:in std_logic;out1:out std_logic);
    end XOR2;
    architecture model_conc3 of XOR2 is
        begin
            out1 <= in1 xor in2 after delay;
    end model_conc3;

    entity ADD3 is
        generic(delay: time);
        port(in1,in2,cin: in std_logic;sum,cout:out std_logic);
    end ADD3;
    architecture model_conc4 of ADD3 is
        begin   
            sum <= (in1 AND NOT in2 AND NOT cin) OR (NOT in1 AND in2 AND NOT cin) OR (NOT in1 AND NOT in2 AND cin) OR (in1 AND in2 AND cin);
            cout <= (in2 AND cin) OR (in1 AND cin) OR (in1 AND in2);
    end model_conc4;

    entity INVERT3 is
        generic(delay:time);
        port(in1,in2,in3:in std_logic; out1:out std_logic);
    end INVERT3;
    architecture model_conc5 of INVERT3 is
        begin
            if (in3=1) then
                out1 <= in1;
            else 
                out1 <= in2;
            end if; 
            after delay;
    end model_conc5;

    entity OPERATION5 is
        generic(delay:time);
        port(in1,in2,in3,in4,in5:in std_logic;out1:out std_logic);
    end OPERATION5;
    architecture model_conc6 of OPERATION5 is
        begin
            if in5=0 then
                out1 <= in1;
            elsif in5=1 then
                out1 <= in2;
            elsif in5=2 then
                out1 <= in3;
            else 
                out1<=in4;
            end if; 
            after delay;
    end model_conc6;




end package body package1;
```

Comment: Entities cannot go in packages,  they are individual design units that live in libraries.

Comment: in addition, `if`, `elsif` and `end if` are sequential statements and are only valid in processes. `after` cannot be synthesised and only makes sense in a testbench.